# How to build a convex curved triangle?

Tags: css, css-shapes

How to build a convex curved triangle with CSS? I just need the top maroon part. It's basically a triangle that curves outward.

I know I need to use calc for height and width. But I don't know where to start.
But I need it to be fatter at the top.

[image]

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid tomato;
  overflow: hidden; 
  transform: rotateY(30deg); */
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%; 
  height: calc(100% - 6px); 
  width: calc(100% - 6px); 
  border-radius: 100% 0% 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border: 3px solid tomato; 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go with skew transformation on pseudo element. You can play with the radius and the skew until you get what you want.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}

.box::before {
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 45px 60px;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
}

.box::after {
  right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 45px 60px;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```